# jQuery - 3つある要素の1つをクリックして右に動かし、残りの2つを元のポジションに戻すコードを書きたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

たとえば、aaa222が右に100px動いていて、bbbをクリックすると、その動いていたaaa222を元の0pxのポジションに戻して、bbb222を右に100px動かしたいです。
ccc222も同じように動いてほしいです。
つまり、右側に動かすのは１つだけで、ほかの２つはクリックされたら、元の0pxに戻る、というプログラムにしたいのですが、どうしたらよいのでしょうか？

```js
<script>
$(function(){
 var duration=300;
 var $a2=$("#aaa222");
 $("#aaa").on("click",function(){
  $a2.toggleClass("goA2");
  if($a2.hasClass("goA2")){
   $a2.stop(true).animate({
    left:100},
    duration);
  }else{
   $a2.stop(true).animate({
    left:0},
    duration);
  }
 })
 
});

$(function(){
 var duration=300;
 var $b2=$("#bbb222");
 $("#bbb").on("click",function(){
  $b2.toggleClass("goB2");
  if($b2.hasClass("goB2")){
   $b2.stop(true).animate({
    left:100},
    duration);
  }else{
   $b2.stop(true).animate({
    left:0},
    duration);
  }
 })
 
});

$(function(){
 var duration=300;
 var $c2=$("#ccc222");
 $("#ccc").on("click",function(){
  $c2.toggleClass("goC2");
  if($c2.hasClass("goC2")){
   $c2.stop(true).animate({
    left:100},
    duration);
  }else{
   $c2.stop(true).animate({
    left:0},
    duration);
  }
 })
 
});

</script>
```

```css
<style>
#aaa{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height:50px;
 background:rgba(0,0,255,1);
 }
#aaa222{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 width:50px;
 height:10px;
 background:rgba(51,255,153,1);
 
 }
#bbb{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height:50px;
 background:rgba(0,255,255,1);
}
#bbb222{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 width:50px;
 height:10px;
 background:rgba(153,51,102,1);
 
 }
#ccc{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:500px;
 height:50px;
 background:rgba(50,100,100,1);
 }
#ccc222{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 top:20px;
 width:50px;
 height:10px;
 background:rgba(153,0,0,1);
 
 }



</style>
```

```html
<body>

<div id="aaa"><div id="aaa222"></div></div>
<div id="bbb"><div id="bbb222"></div></div>
<div id="ccc"><div id="ccc222"></div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

色々やり方はあると思いますが、
以下の様にすればいいかと思います。

```
$(function(){
    var duration=300;
    $("#aaa222,#bbb222,#ccc222").bind("move", function(e, myID){
    //クラスの代わりにIDを使うことにした。既に効果が適用されているかどうかのチェックは行わないことにしている。
        if($(this).attr("id")==myID){
            $(this).stop(true)
                   .animate({left:100},duration);
        } else {
            $(this).stop(true)
                   .animate({left:0},duration);
        }
    });

    $("#aaa,#bbb,#ccc").on("click",function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr("id") + 222;//親要素と規則性がある
        //それぞれに効果を呼び出す（カスタムイベント発火）
        $("#aaa222").triggerHandler("move", ID);
        $("#bbb222").triggerHandler("move", ID);
        $("#ccc222").triggerHandler("move", ID);
    });
});
```

Comment: すごく勉強になりました！
同じコメントになりますが、自分の弱点がわかりちょっと前進しました。
感謝いたします！

Answer (score 2):

一つのイベントから3つのエレメントを動かしたいならそういうプログラムにする必要があると思います。
onのハンドラの中に

```
$('#aaa222,#bbb2222,#ccc222').each(function(i, bar){
    if(イベントが起きたのが自分か){
         $(bar).stop().animate({left:100, duration:300});
    } else {
        $(bar).stop().animate({left:0, duration:300});
    }
});
```

のような処理を書く必要があるでしょう。
全部書くと、それはつまり私のためにプログラムを書いてくださいということとほぼ等しくなってしまうのでこれだけにしておきます。
アドバイスとして言えることは、バブリングに注意してください。というくらいですかね。

Comment: すみません。。。
もう少し、具体的に書いていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。。。

Answer (score 2):

もう一つ`<div>`を追加して、各要素にクラスを割り当てれば以下のように書けます。
(`<div>`は追加する必要はないんですが、実用的ではないので･･･)

```js
<script>
$(function(){
    var duration=300;
    $(document).on('click', '.parent', function(){
        $(this).siblings().find('.child').stop(true).animate({left:0}, duration);
        $(this).find('.child').stop(true).animate({left:100}, duration);
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<div>
    <div id="aaa" class="parent"><div id="aaa222" class="child"></div></div>
    <div id="bbb" class="parent"><div id="bbb222" class="child"></div></div>
    <div id="ccc" class="parent"><div id="ccc222" class="child"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: すごく勉強になりました！
自分が何がわかっていないのかがわかって、ちょっと前進しました。
感謝いたします！